# Handling custom errors with a port in the URL for IIS

Tags: iis, ports, custom-errors

I am trying to specify a custom (ASPX) page to handle 404 errors.

I can't seem to do this with IIS because I use a port other than the default.

I have two versions of my site, one exposed (default port) and one on another port, for testing. I'm trying to do this in testing mode first.

If I do:
http://www.mysite.com/notapage ... I get the IIS 404 error.

If I do:
http://www.mysite.com:1234/notapage ... I get a Google error (I use Google Chrome) as if it cannot resolve my site even though http://www.mysite.com/ works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which level you configure this ASPX page for 404? If you did that on default web site, it only works for first test link you provided.

port 1234 should be monitored by another web site. Please check your IIS settings and make sure that that site was configured correctly.